# Automate Attachment Save

Tags: vba, outlook

So, the goal is that when I receive an email from a customer, containing the desired attachment, save the attachment to a location of my choosing.

**This is my new code, it compiles but doesn't output the file?**

Thanks in advance.

```
Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Set olApp = Outlook.Application
    Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Items = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
End Sub

Private Sub Application_NewMail()

Dim oInbox As MAPIFolder
Dim oItem As MailItem

Set oInbox = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set oItem = oInbox.Items.GetLast

'Only act if it's a MailItem
Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem
If TypeName(item) = "MailItem" Then
    Set Msg = oItem

    'Change variables to match need. Comment or delete any part unnecessary.
    If (Msg.SenderName = "Name Of Person") And _
        (Msg.Subject = "Subject to Find") And _
        (Msg.Attachments.Count >= 1) Then

        'Set folder to save in.
        Dim olDestFldr As Outlook.MAPIFolder
        Dim myAttachments As Outlook.Attachments
        Dim Att As String

        'location to save in.  Can be root drive or mapped network drive.
        Const attPath As String = "C:\"

        ' save attachment
        Set myAttachments = item.Attachments
        Att = myAttachments.item(1).DisplayName
        myAttachments.item(1).SaveAsFile attPath & Att

        ' mark as read
       Msg.UnRead = False
    End If
End If

ProgramExit:
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
    Resume ProgramExit
End Sub
```

Comment: When I actually run the code I replace the parameters with my display name, and subject 'Test' and then send myself an email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you open the VBA window, you will see the object called "ThisOutlookSession", which is where you place the code.

This event is triggered automatically upon reception of a new email received:

```
Private Sub Application_NewMail()

Dim oInbox As MAPIFolder
Dim oItem As MailItem


Set oInbox = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set oItem = oInbox.Items.GetLast

//MsgBox oItem.To
//Etcetera 

End Sub
```

About your edit, I didn't really investigate why it didn't work, but you can use this, which I tested:

```
Dim atmt As Outlook.Attachment
Dim Att As String
Const attPath As String = "U:\"


For Each atmt In Msg.Attachments
    Att = atmt.DisplayName
    atmt.SaveAsFile attPath & Att
Next
```

Note that it may seem as if you didn't save the file, because you cannot use 'Date modified' in WinExplorer to show the latest saved attachment (I noticed just now). But you can look it up alphabetically.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. From my above code I changed Application_Startup() to Application_NewMail().. is this all I have to do? I've been playing around with it and can't get it to work.

Comment: No, Application_Startup is just code that is executed upon startup of Outlook. In your example code, I read the line: Set Msg = item What you could do is Set Msg = oItem and copy - paste the code as from here into the Application_NewMail (after the example that I have posted).

Comment: See my edit please, I think I've followed your instructions and I think I'm nearly there.

Comment: Where within the code do I place this? And won't this save every attachment? Thanks

Comment: Also the file is definitely not there.. in reference to your 'date modified' idea.

Comment: Well, I actually tried your code and it works. However, you need to replace: item.Attachments  with msg.Attachments